# Fish Shell to Truncate list of files

Tags: fish

In bash if I wish to truncate a bunch of files in a directory, I would do the following:

```
for i in *
do
    cat /dev/null > $i
done
```

In fish, I tried:

```
for I in *
    cat /dev/null > $I
end
```

but that gives me the error:

```
fish: Invalid redirection target: $I
```

So anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me. Note that the only way you'll get that error is if variable `I` is not set. I noticed you used a lowercase letter for your bash example and uppercase for the fish example. Did you perhaps mix the case? For example, this will cause the error you saw:

```
for i in *
    true > $I
end
```

P.S., In a POSIX shell it's more efficient to do `: > $i`. Since fish doesn't support `:` it's more efficient to do `true > $i` to avoid spawning an external command and opening /dev/null.

Comment: I used I in the fish example to differ it from the bash example.  But I think you are correct, I noticed when typing it in again, that fish was changing the case of my variable names as I typed.  weird.  thanks for the sanity check.